# NextCloud: Append only?

Tags: nextcloud

I know how to make an upload dir and how to make a read-only dir. Can I combine those?

I want people to be able to upload but not change existing files uploaded by others. They should, however, be able to see the files uploaded by others. The uploaders will only use this once and will therefore not have an account on my NextCloud installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, right now you can't do this in Nextcloud. A work-around would be to create a file-drop link AND a read-only link, so they can see in the read-only link and upload in the file-drop link ;-)

You can create multiple upload links by entering an email address. The recipient gets a link by mail which you can configure separately. So, for example, you create a read-only public link and share that with ppl. Then everyone you want to give upload rights you sent a file-drop link via mail ;-)